# Solving the initial value problem for the discrete nonlinear Schrödinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, nonlinear-analysis

The continuum (cubic) NLS has a standing wave solution, for $\omega < 0$ ,

$$u_{\omega}(x,t) = e^{-i \omega t} \psi_{|\omega|}(x),$$
where $\psi_{|\omega|}(x)$ is the unique solution to the nonlinear elliptic problem
\begin{align}-\Delta_{x}\psi_{|\omega|} - |\psi_{|\omega|}|^{2}\psi_{|\omega|} &= \omega \psi_{|\omega|}, \tag{1}\end{align}
which is real-valued, radially symmetric, and decreasing to zero at spatial infinity.

In [1], they consider solving the initial value problem for discrete nonlinear Schrödinger equation (DNLS)

\begin{align}
i \partial_{t}u_{n}(t) &= -h^{-2} \left ( \delta^{2} u\right )_n - |u_n|^{2}u_n, \; n\in\mathbb{Z}^{d} \tag{2}
\end{align}

in spatial dimension $d=1$ with the initial condition

\begin{align}
u_{n}(0) &= e^{i \nu \cdot x_{n}}\psi_{|\omega|}(x_{n}),\; x_{n}=nh,\; n\in \mathbb{Z} \tag{3}
\end{align}

How can they use $\psi_{|\omega|}$  in their initial condition if we do not know what it actually is? In (1.3) they say there exist a unique solution, but what is it?

---

[1] - https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3892